# Validating (checking) a path entered exists

Tags: c#, validation, path

I have a program which has a file watcher, who's path is entered (set) by the user. The user enters the path in a text box then a click of the button sets the file watcher's path

```
private void btnFileWatcherPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fileWatcher.Path = txtFileWatcherPath.Text;
}
```

The file watcher is turned on with another button (off button also in the program)

```
private void btnFileOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    btnFileOn.Visible = false;
    btnFileOff.Visible = true;
}
```

The program works but I have no validating of the path. Any invalid paths entered crashes the program. How can I stop this (would like a label to display something like "invalid path entered")

Comment: Wasn't clear enough, sorry was a file system watcher. Am looking at a whole directory not just a file. Just changed the File.Exist to a Directory.Exist and does the job. Cheers guys and thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `File.Exists`

```
private void btnFileWatcherPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(File.Exists(txtFileWatcherPath.Text)){
        fileWatcher.Path = txtFileWatcherPath.Text;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx)

```
if(File.Exists(path)){
    //Do some stuff
}
else{
    //It's bad man
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it ina try catch block, and then handle the io exception if the path is not found

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use file watcher for such a purpose.

Try using Directory.Exists (if its a directory you're checking)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Validate that the path exists via either of these methods:

```
string path = txtFileWatcherPath.Text;
```

This (for the directory):

```
System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
```

or this (for the actual file):

```
System.IO.File.Exists(path);
```